# Casting in specific code C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml

Can someone explain me using the example below how type casting works.
I came accross this code in a virtual academy session from microsoft:
[Windows Phone 8.1 Development for Absolute Beginners](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-phone-8-1-development-for-absolute-beginners) => Overview of common xaml controls

```
myTextBlock.Text = ((ComboBoxItem)Combo.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

For those who see this as a duplicate, for me its about this specific code, not the explanation behind casting.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) Helps but i cant use it to explain code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedItem is declared as Object

(ComboBoxItem)Combo.SelectedItem cast to the ComboBoxItem type

((ComboBoxItem)Combo.SelectedItem) makes you access SelectedItem as a ComboBoxItem

Comment: Why didnt they do something like this:
myTextBlock.Text = Combo.SelectedItem.Content.ToString();

Comment: Because Content don't exist on the "object" type, but exists on the "ComboBoxItem" type. Such a line would cause a compilation error.

Comment: Ok, (maybe) strange SelectedItem has no Content.
Or Maybe that's because SelectedItem is to generic and is used in many cases (Also objects without Content)?